# help me understand Rails and attributes as class methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, idioms

This is from the *Hartl Rails tutorial*. We are automatically logging in a user in the process of creating that user with a callback to `#create_remember_token`. It works great but there are some things, I am not clear on. Please bear with me as I'm thoroughly confused to the point that I don't even know how to ask my question.

I have a user model:

```
class User<ActiveRecord::Base
...
...

before_create :create_remember_token
def User.new_remember_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def User.encrypt(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
  end
```

...

I am confused about the `::new_remember_token` and the encrypt being methods attached to `User`. It looks as though they are attributes of `User` like `name`, `email`, `password` etc, because they are being accessed with dot notation. But they are defined like methods and seem to return a computed value. I don't understand, why an attribute of the `User` model is referred to with `self` for assigning `self.remember_token` and `User.encrypt` for accessing the class method.

---

**My question**

What's the difference between the above and the following where `User`, is replaced with `self`. ?

```
class User<ActiveRecord::Base
...
...

before_create :create_remember_token
def new_remember_token
  SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end

def encrypt(token)
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
end

private

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = self.encrypt(self.new_remember_token)
  end
```

...

I'm a novice in the *ruby* language, but pretty good with javascript, so if there's a *js* analog it might help me to put it in those terms.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently working on the User model within ruby as you look down you code you can see

def function

end

That creates a function that exists within the User class, so in theory from most anywhere else in your application you could do User.some_function, you only use self.some_function from within the class.

There isn't any difference between using User.encrypt and self.encrypt except that its safer,  self.function means only look inside the current class.

I think you're probably getting attributes and functions mixed up because you're not seeing the () at the end of function calls, you don't actually use those in ruby unless you passing parameters to the function.

Where you're mentioning username, password, email etc those are fields associated with the database and are attributes.

The concept to understand here is that the User model represents the association with the underlying database, you can(as you have there) add extra functionality to ensure the quality of the data going in for example:

```
before_create :create_remember_token
```

That means that if ANYWHERE within you application you create a new user the model calls that function as part of the process of creating the record. Essentially by building functionality into models you can ensure that all data going into the database is treated in the same way.

Comment: helpful because it's helping me formulate my question.  will edit my original question for clarity.

Comment: No problem I started rails a few months ago and the learning curve is steep!

Comment: @tim please note that if the edit to the question is a *different* question than the one currently being asked, it *may* be better to ask a new question.  Each question should ask only one question, and the answers to that question should answer only that question.

Comment: @MichaelT ok.  i'll make sure it gets straightened out once i figure out what im trying to ask.  thanks to Mrk Fldig for helping nudge me in that direction.

Comment: @tim one of the hardest switches in thinking on Stack Exchange is how this isn't a forum - the back and forth takes place in comments or new questions if the issue brought up is a new question itself.  When this lightbulb goes on as to how things work, the system becomes much easier to work in and with (and you find yourself asking better questions for more rep).

Comment: @MichaelT I rearranged and reworded my question a bit.  Is it more in line with what you are looking for?

Comment: Right I gotcha, let me edit my answer...

Comment: ok.  so is there no fundamental difference between looking down at my code and seeing def myfunction and seeing def MyModelName.myfunction  ?

Comment: You wouldn't use classname.function_name in a DEF statement because your defining the function inside the class itself

Comment: self.my_function is the same as doing classname.myfunction, but if you calling a function that is in the same class as your code always use self as it prevents any mishaps later on

Comment: ok that's why im confused, because in the Hartl tutorial he uses classname.function_name in a def statement.  Why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11932/discussion-between-tim-and-mrk-fldig)

Comment: Ok i'm in chat.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why an attribute of the User model is referred to with self for assigning self.remember_token and User.encrypt for accessing the class method.
>   What's the difference between the above and the following where User. is replaced with self.

Functionally there is no difference between `User`, and `self` in the context of class `User`, but the differs to each other in the context of `User` class instance. So for the context `User` class you are able to call the `::new_remember_token` methods as both of `User` class, and `self`, and they return the same (for the context) results.

```
self.new_remember_token

User.new_remember_token
```

However, as you correctly denote, that attribute of the `User` model is referred to both with `self`, and with `User`. So I believe, the author put that difference by the two main reasons:

1. Since the `::new_remember_token` is declared as of the property the class `User` itself, i.e. as a singleton method, the call to it shell be done with call to the class `User` ifself, in case when `self` isn't `User` class, or to using `self` operator, when `self === User`.
2. In order to split meanings of real properties that is mirrored unto DB, and the class singleton methods that have no that function. So you saw:

   ```
   self.remember_token = ... # call to property 'remember_token'

   User.new_remember_token # call to User model's singleton method
   ```

   However, the `#new_remember_token` could be declared as of `User` instance method as follows:

   ```
   def new_remember_token
      ...
   end
   ```

   And call to it shell be done with:

   ```
   self.remember_token = self.encrypt(self.new_remember_token)
   ```

   But the author have in mind that the purpose of the `::new_remember_token` method isn't the same as of attributes.